# Register for COM Interoperability

Tags: c#, excel, vba, com, interop

I create the following class library in C#:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
//[Guid(<Generate GUID here>)]
public interface _None1
{
    int retval { get; }
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
//[Guid(<Generate GUID here>)]
[ProgId("Lotr.Test")]
public class None : _None1
{
    public int retval
    {
        get
        { return 1; }
    }
}
```

Then I compile it using "Register for COM Interop" and "Make Assembly COM-visible" options.
When I try to access it using Excel 2007 VBA on my machine, works fine. However, if I take the .dll and .tlb files to another machine, and then use regasm to register it, the registration happens fine, I am able to reference this in Excel VBA via the tlb, the intellisense works like clockwork, but while execution, VBA runtime gives the following error:
"Runtime error:-2147024894 (80070002)"
"Automation Error: The system cannot find the file specified."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use `/codebase` regasm key:

```
regasm your_assembly_name.dll /codebase
```

Comment: Yup.  Or install it in the GAC, a counter-measure against COM's notorious DLL Hell problem.

Comment: OMG, after days of trying everything I could find, /codebase finally did the trick. Sadly, I don't know why - what exactly is /codebase doing?

Comment: `/codebase` simply writes assembly file path to the registry. By default (without this flag) it is assumed that assembly is installed in GAC. More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've some things diferents in my COM assemblies:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
//[Guid(<Generate GUID here>)]
public interface _None1
{
    [DispId(1)]
    int retval { get; }
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
//[Guid(<Generate GUID here>)]
[ProgId("Lotr.Test")]
public class None : _None1
{
    [STAThread]
    public int retval
    {
        get
        { return 1; }
    }
}
```

and I don't know if in a COM interface you can use getter and setter operations... maybe someone knows and help us :)